# TypeError: require.config is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, brunch

I am using require.js as part of a brunch project. This code is throwing the error:

```
;require.config({ // require.config is not a function
paths: {
   jquery: "lib/jquery",
   underscore: "lib/underscore",
   backbone: "lib/backbone",
   localstorage: "lib/backbone.localStorage"
}
});
```

Does that mean that requirejs is not getting included properly in the project?

Answer (score 17):

If you get that error, it could be that:

- RequireJS is not loaded.

  This can diagnosed by opening the browser's debugger to look at network requests and seeing whether the file that defines `require` is asked by the browser and checking that the response indicates that the data is available (i.e. loaded from the server, loaded from cache).
- RequireJS is loaded but not initializing properly.

  This could happen if something is loaded before RequireJS and somehow messes with the JavaScript runtime in a way that makes RequireJS fail to initialize. For instance, if something puts in the global space a global named `define` of any type, or global named `requirejs` and which is a function, then RequireJS will silently abandon initializing.

  I'd diagnose this with breakpoints in the file that contains RequireJS to see whether it completes execution or not.
- RequireJS is loaded but something else redefines `require`.

  I'd inspect the value of `require` *just after* RequireJS is loaded. If it has a `config` method defined at that point, then something else must be messing with it later.