# require.config is not a function in .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using .js file and I have just played with the code and I found out the error

require.config is not a function
What I can do for this? Please help me out!

The code is here

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'mobiledetect': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.4.4/mobile-detect.min'
  }
});
require(['mobiledetect'], function (MobileDetect) {
  var detector = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent)

  console.log("Mobile: " + detector.mobile());
  console.log("Phone: " + detector.phone());
  console.log("Tablet: " + detector.tablet());
  console.log("OS: " + detector.os());
  console.log("userAgent: " + detector.userAgent());

});
```

Best regards,
Paresh Pawar

Comment: is this what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20876136/typeerror-require-config-is-not-a-function

Comment: Pranav, I am not sure what is the problem and I am not from developer background...I do marketing...

Comment: Please follow this page https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?
 Javascript doesn't have a native module called require 
Maybe you need to install a dependency for this to work